# Why is this C++ code triggering a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Why is my C++ code triggering a stack overflow?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    cout<<"Enter an odd number for the order of magic square: ";
    cin>>num;

    int sqr[5][5];

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        for (int j=0;j<num; j++)
            sqr [i][j]=0;

   return 0;
```

}

Comment: Where is `num` declared?

Comment: This happens if you key in values greater than 5 for num.

Comment: @Arun: I think it could also happen if you entered a non-integer.

Comment: @FredLarson, yeah right.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sqr[5][5];
```

You defined `sqr` as double dimension array which `col and row` are both 5. The valid `col/row` are between `[0..4]`, You need to make sure `num < 5 && num > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use`vector<vector<int> >`,  whose size be dynamically increased,

or change your code to

```
for (int i=0; i<num &&i < 5; i++)
    for (int j=0;j<num && j < 5; j++)
        sqr [i][j]=0;
```

since your declaration of sqr is `sqr[5][5]`.

Comment: doesn't work. it doesn't even let me input any number

Comment: what num you want to input

Answer (score 0):

may be there should exists:
int num;
or num may become a large number,resulting from a string.
add:
printf("%d",num);
for test to see if it is larger than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to create an n x n matrix based on input 'n'?

If so, you shouldn't statically allocate the matrix (see other answers for why).
Assert if 'n' is not a number.

To create the matrix:

```
int **sqr = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sqr[i] = new int[n];
```

This creates your created a 2D matrix of order n x n.
To index into it, you can use sqr[row][col] 
(Remember: x denotes columns, y denotes rows! And don't forget to delete all this memory!)

If you want to use STL, then you can use create a vector of vectors without doing all this C style pointer stuff!